# NGINX: Primary script unknown - when calling a dynamic URL with controller prefix

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker-compose

We facing a problem and we can't fix it. We are currently able to run our application as expected - SEO URL runs like a charm and are rewriting to `index.php`. The problem is, we have an additional URL Pattern like:

- `/controllerPrefix/a-param.php`
- `/controllerPrefix/an-other-param.php`
- `/controllerPrefix/an-other-other-param.php`

...which we need to rewrite to `index.php` too. We are unable to write this URL dynamic URL which ends in `.php`. Please note that there are no physical PHP files e.g. `a-param.php` -> it's a dynamic pattern which ends in `.php`. Unfortunately, the output in browser is `File not found.` The following error is  logged in **nginx 1.10**:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream...

-> **404 not found**

#### NGNIX Configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

How to rewrite this dynamic URL ending in `/controllerPrefix/*.php` to `index.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

Either 1) redirect **all** URIs ending with `.php` to `/index.php`, if there is no matching script file - add a `try_files` statement to the existing `location ~ \.php$` block (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    ...
}
```

---

Or, 2) redirect URIs that begin with `/controllerPrefixng` to `/index.php` - add a new `location` block (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details):

```
location ^~ /controllerPrefix/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```